# Python regular expression syntax error

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will match a `-` (dash), followed by as many letters as it possibly can. What I have at the moment, is the following: `exp = (-[a-z A-z]*)`.
I am getting a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error though.

Comment: Every regular expression in Python must be placed in a string literal

Comment: Please post the full lines of code you are using.  Thanks.

Comment: to expand on @vaultah's comment you need to make the expression a string: `exp = "(-[a-z A-z]*)"` otherwise you try to define a **python** expression which doesn't like that syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try placing your expression in a string

```
import re
exp = re.compile('(-[a-z A-z]*)')
```

cheers